# Access file of one instance by tomcat running on other instance in AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, web-deployment, amazon-ec2

I have two AWS-EC2 linux instance.
One for DB and doc files and other for tomcat on which java application is running.
I have an scenario, in which user can download files i.e. which is located on second instance.
I google for it, I got some options like NFS, FTP etc. , I am not sure which one is good in terms of performance as well as security.
Thanks.

Comment: fyi, you can use s3/cloudfront for storing and fetching static files - a better option than using a second ec2 server.

Comment: Thanks. But it is design like this, and I can't go for s3.

Comment: Are the files going to be exchanged between the two servers or the links to the files present in server1 are available via the application running on server2 on the web? What sort of performance/traffic figures are you looking at?

Answer (score 0):

One way that makes use of services already available is SCP.

First, generate a key pair:

```
$ ssh-keygen -b 4096 -C "tomcat-servlet-key"
```

Save the private key on the Tomcat instance as `/path/to/my-key`, and copy the contents of `/path/to/my-key.pub` to `/home/fileowner/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the file storage instance. (See [AWS docs on adding users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html) for info on how to add the *fileowner* user, and make sure *fileowner* has read permissions on the files to be served.)

You can use the [Ant Scp task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) to make things a little easier in your servlet code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

public class ScpServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String SERVER_2_USER = "fileowner";
    private static final String SERVER_2_PRIVATE_IP = "10.0.0.xyz";
    private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "/path/to/my-key";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Scp scp = new Scp();
        scp.setProject(new Project());
        scp.setRemoteFile(SERVER_2_USER + '@' + SERVER_2_PRIVATE_IP + ":/tmp/hello.txt");
        File outfile = File.createTempFile("hello", ".txt");
        try {
            scp.setLocalTofile(outfile.getAbsolutePath());
            scp.setKeyfile(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);
            scp.setHost(SERVER_2_PRIVATE_IP);
            scp.setUsername(SERVER_2_USER);
            scp.setTrust(true);
            scp.execute();
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
                Files.asByteSource(outfile).copyTo(out);
            }
        } finally {
            outfile.delete();
        }
    }

}
```

You can lock down the file storage instance in a security group that only allows access from other instances in the VPC.

This solution has an unnecessary intermediate step of copying the file to disk on the Tomcat instance to serve it from there, but you might be able to extend the Scp task to keep the bytes in memory.